# TimeMachine Backup Never Runs due to 123+ Million Changes

Tags: macbook-pro, backup, time-machine

For two weeks I've been trying to make a backup of my MBP (I got a new MBP from work and I need to return the old one asap, but first I really need a backup!). The last backup was a bit more than a month ago.

However, there are +80M changes, and it takes hours for it to just detect all the changes. It also never finishes this process, at some point it just stops, and then I have to retry (80M is the highest I've seen before it failed, could be more).

It's a 2019 i9 16GB MBP and other than this issue it's working perfectly.

There's only 140GB of data on my machine, and my external SSD has 1.7TB free.

Does anyone know or have any ideas on how I can get this backup working?

Thanks!

EDIT to answer the questions in the comments:

Still running with now ~106M~ ~113M~ 123M changes.

[image: Screenshot of TimeMachine changes]

*How long have you left it? What happens if you leave it overnight?* More than 12 hours, the problem is not waiting longer the problem is that TM just crashes.

*Do you think you might have 10s of millions of files, or not?* I don't think so. The only thing that comes to mind are multiple (~10) Node/React projects. Otherwise not much data on it, no pictures, some downloads, and few documents

*Also, what OS are you running, and what format is the TM drive?* 13.4.1 (22F82) and APFS (Case-sensitive, Encrypted).

*Is this the first Time Machine backup you're trying to run?* Nope, I have had macs for years, and have backed up the current device many times. The external disk is relatively new and only has two prior backups, both about 1-2 months ago.

*If not, you might want format the drive (APFS), then make a clean backup to your Time Machine* I'd rather not format the drive since it contains a lot of stuff I need. Also I'm not sure the drive is the problem?

*Backup all important local files to a cloud service* That's an option, most of my files are already in the cloud, but I still would like to get TM working. BTW, I'm not using the backup to migrate everything to the new mac. I'd rather start with a clean mac, but want the data so I can copy some specific files I need.

Comment: How long have you left it? What happens if you leave it overnight? Do you think you might have 10s of millions of files, or not? Also, what OS are you running, and what format is the TM drive?

Comment: Is this the first Time Machine backup you're trying to run?  If not, you might want   format the drive (APFS), then make a clean backup to your Time Machine.

Comment: Where I work, before an upgrade to a newer Mac, our employees are asked to backup all important _local_ files to a cloud service and we assist them in using Migration Assistant with a direct wired connection between old <> new instead of relying on Time Machine restores. With the right mind-set (all work-related files MUST be kept cloud-based, for example) Time Machine is removed from the equation. We had enough TM glitches to make the MA method work much better.

Comment: @IconDaemon - I've even had migrations silently fail. No doubt you must have copies of everything, everywhere. Belt & braces. I have mine on Time Machine *and* in the cloud. Also I was in that instance adding a Mac to the family rather than discarding the older one afterwards, so the missing data was still in place on the older Mac. Though it took me a couple of days to identify the issue, it was easily correctable.

Comment: I've tried to answer your questions and updated the post. Thanks!

Comment: Good additional info. tbh, i would abandon this one & make a fresh backup. Whether you do this on a completely new drive or by splitting the APFS into two distinct containers I think is optional. I think I would err on the side of caution & use a new drive.

Comment: @Tetsujin, how can I make a 'clean' backup if I don't want to delete the data in the old backups already on disk? I couldn't find anything, so I can only think of partitioning and starting on a new empty partition. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: As above - best bet is a completely new drive.

Comment: My thinking is the backup journal might be corrupt.  Instead of trying to isolate it, just create a nice new (clean) backup

Comment: I would second reformatting the partition you're currently using to APFS and re-creating the backup. Time Machine backups to APFS use a different process for change detection.

Comment: @Ezekiel - OP wants to keep some of the data in the history on that one, which is why I think a new drive is best bet. It's certainly the safest option. I'd also think twice before using encryption or indeed Case-Sensitive on backups. [I'd always say for case-sensitive on anything Apple you need to know why you need it… and if you can't answer that, don't use it.]

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I've ordered a new drive, just so I'll be done with it asap Although it still confuses me that this is the 'best' option. I'm wondering, can't I just tell TM to make a new backup without considering changes next to the old backup?

Comment: "...that this is the 'best' option" - My USD$0.02: Drives are inexpensive; your data is _priceless_. I swap out TM disks every 2 years and I have multiple concurrent physical drives at present. There's a shelf of old HDs which I may make into a freestanding sculpture some day.

Comment: @picklepick With APFS it's trivial to add a new backup target and just restart there - unfortunately less flexible without APFS since you'd need to create a whole new partition.

Comment: @IconDaemon I agree, but this drive is a new (bought in April) 2TB SSD not quite 'cheap' (for me at least). So just buying a new one without trying to solve the problem feels wasteful.

Comment: @Ezekiel: I'm on APFS, but a quick Google search didn't show me something trivial, would you care to elaborate on how I can create a new target?

Comment: @picklepick The target needs to be APFS. In Disk Utility, select the APFS container (or any volume inside the container) and choose Edit > Add APFS Volume. Choose APFS or APFS (Encrypted) and give it a name. Then, in Time Machine settings choose this new volume as your backup destination.